# Controlling Gradle task execution

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my build.gradle script, I have a lot of tasks, each depending on zero or more other tasks.

There are three 'main' tasks which can be called: `moduleInstallation`, `backupFiles` and `restoreFiles`.

Here's the question: I would like to be able to tell Gradle which tasks to execute and which don't need to execute. For example, when calling `moduleInstallation`, I want all depending tasks to execute (regardless of their `UP-TO-DATE flag`), but **not** the restore tasks. I've tried altering the phase in which the tasks get executed (e.g. config phase, execution phase,...) and a couple of other things, but all tasks just keep getting executed.

A solution I've thought of was just stating in the main tasks that, when this main task is called (f.e. `moduleInstallation`), we set the `UP-TO-DATE flag` of all non-related tasks to false, so they don't get executed. Is that possible?

**EDIT:** Here's an example:

When `moduleInstallation` is called (which depends on `backupFiles`), `restoreFiles` (which depends on `restoreFromDate`) is executed too.

**First main action**

```
task moduleInstallation << {
    println "Hello from moduleInstallation"
}

task backupFiles {
    doLast {
        println "Hello from backupFiles"
    }
}
```

**Second main action**

```
task restoreFiles {
    println "Hello from restoreFiles"
}

task restoreFromDate {
    println "Hello from restoreFromDate"
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
moduleInstallation.dependsOn backupFiles 
restoreFiles.dependsOn restoreFromDate
```

So when I type `gradle moduleInstallation` in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
Hello from restoreFromDate
Hello from restoreFiles
Hello from backupFiles
Hello from moduleInstallation
```

Comment: The way to tell Gradle which other tasks to execute is to establish the correct task dependencies. Why would you only want to execute a subset of task dependencies?

Comment: @Peter: As stated, the dependencies are correct. It's just that I want to have 1 script giving the user 3 possible main actions (each existing of different tasks and dependencies) which don't have anything to do with each other. And because they have nothing to do with each other, they shouldn't execute when another main action is wanted.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your build script. Please provide a minimal self-contained example.

Comment: It doesn't help because it doesn't allow to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Another update. I hope this helps to visualise the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29361/discussion-between-dreamonic-and-peter-niederwieser)

Answer (score 3):

The second snippet has to use `doLast` (or its `<<` shortcut) like the first snippet. Otherwise, the code is configuration code and will *always* be evaluated, no matter which tasks are eventually going to be executed. In other words, it's not the `restoreFiles` and `restoreFromDate` tasks that are being executed here (as one can tell from the bits of command line output that you don't show), but (only) their configuration code.

To better understand what's going on here (which is crucial for understanding Gradle), I recommend to study the [Build Lifecycle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#build_lifecycle) chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Makes sense. So I'd have to make all tasks use `<<`?

Comment: All code that should be run if and when the task gets executed needs to go into `doLast { ... }` or `<< { ... }`. (Both `doLast` and `<<` add a *task action* to the task.) I recommend to use `doLast` because it leads to a more regular syntax and is less likely added/omitted accidentally.

Comment: I only noticed now: if I use `doLast` or `<<`, most of the tasks indicate they're `UP-TO-DATE`, even though I added `allprojects {
    tasks.all {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    }
}`
at the beginning of the build script...

Comment: Some tasks also print `UP-TO-DATE` when they have nothing to do (no inputs). Setting `upToDateWhen { false }` for all tasks shouldn't ever be necessary. Anyway, that's a different question.